Set-Cookie not used in subsequent request in Cordova/Android
I know that this topic was already discussed but I cannot figured out the issue.

Client : Cordova App running on Android emulator (localhost)
Server : remote server

Flow :

1-Client send through POST login credentials
2-Server respond with Set-Cookie: TOKEN=TOKEN
3-Client send another request (should include the cookie)

2-Server Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost
Content-Length: 757
Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'self' data: blob:;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
Date: Fri, 05 Apr 2024 22:55:12 GMT
Etag: W/"2f5-cF2DgIYE70TbTgbAxYrSxvRZvYU"
Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?1
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: TOKEN=CONTENT; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 06 Apr 2024 22:55:11 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Xss-Protection: 0

3-Client Request
:Authority: remote.server.dns.com
:Method: GET
:Path: /api/route
:Scheme: https
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://remote.server.dns.com:443
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin: https://localhost
Referer: https://localhost/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 14; sdk_gphone64_x86_64 Build/UE1A.230829.036.A1; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/113.0.5672.136 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: com.dns.sub

So the server reject the (3) because the route api/route is secured and require the cookie...
Help ?
Note: I am not asking about cookie persistency nor client-side cookie definition ;)
What I tried :

w/ or w/o Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
w/ or w/o Access-Control-Allow-Origin
w/ or w/o many cordova plugins...
asking chatgpt but...chatgpt...


Solution :
The problem was not related to cordova/android.
This issue was that I did not flag my XHR request with credential = true to allow sent of cookie/authorization in cross domain.
For fetch(...) use credentials:"include" like :
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    credentials: "include",
    body: new Blob([JSON.stringify(params)], { type: "application/json" }),
})

For XMLHttpRequest use withCredentials = true like :
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
...
xhr.send();

